# How to configure Dockerfile to work with Puppeteer?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, puppeteer

I"m trying to get Puppeteer 21.7 working in my Docker container running node.js-16.

I've done a bunch of digging and tried a number of things, but I continue to get the error:

```
Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 119.0.6045.105). This can occur if either
 1. You did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npx puppeteer browsers install chrome`) or
 2. Your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /usr/src/app/.cache/puppeteer).
```

Below is my dockerfile I use to build the container. What am I missing or need to configure to get this working?

```
# Use the official Node.js image.
FROM node:16-slim

# Install required system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -yq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus- 
1-3 \ libgbm-dev libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 
libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 \ libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1  \ libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 \ ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget 

# Create and change to the app directory.
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Create a directory for the Puppeteer cache in the root project.
RUN mkdir /.cache

# Copy the .puppeteerrc.cjs file into the Docker image.
COPY .puppeteerrc.cjs /usr/src/app/.puppeteerrc.cjs

# Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
# A wildcard is used to ensure copying both package.json AND package-lock.json (when 
 available).
# Copying this first prevents re-running npm install on every code change.
COPY package*.json ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN npm install --only=production

# Install Puppeteer.
RUN npm install puppeteer
RUN npx puppeteer install


# Set the environment variable for Puppeteer's download path.
ENV PUPPETEER_DOWNLOAD_PATH=/.cache/puppeteer

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . ./

# Run the web service on container startup.
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Comment: Hello,
based on the documentation https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.configuration/#properties seems you are missing env for PUPPETEER_CACHE_DIR and PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH to be the same as PUPPETEER_DOWNLOAD_PATH because, when you install it tries to execute the browser from default which points to $HOME/.cache/puppeteer
Can you try and see the result.